# Get specific (name) value from wcf dataservice

Tags: c#, wcf, var, dataservice

I want to get the name of the product which i've selected in my gridview.
I have a index number which I can use to compare in my database, but I can't select the name of the item which belongs to that index number.

```
ServiceReference1.ProductContext ctx = new ServiceReference1.ProductContext(new Uri("http://SERVER:5000/WcfDataService1.svc/"));

DbList = ctx.Products;
int index = ProductsList.SelectedIndex;

string name = DbList.XXXXXXX  // -> ?????????
```

Everything what i've tried ended up in a exception. Any ideas how to get the product name?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If `ProductsList` is a drop down or other list, something like `ProductsList.SelectedValue` might do the trick.

Comment: that returns the name of the ProductsList only. No content :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simon at rcl and LaMMMy helped me in the right direction. Thank you!

So my solution for the problem is:

```
ServiceReference1.Product product = (ServiceReference1.Product)this.ProductsList.Items[productIndex];
string name = product.Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like (this is air code so might not be right):

```
Product product = DBList.Where<Product>((p) => p.Id == index);
```

This assumes that DBList is a list of type product, and that a Product has an Id property which matches the index you're looking for.

You can then do

```
string name = product.Name;
```

etc etc etc.

Comment: Yess,
This helped me in the right direction. Solution: 

    ServiceReference1.Product product = (ServiceReference1.Product).ProductsList.Items[Index];

Answer (score 1):

Could you do

```
Product myProduct = ctx.Products.Find(index);
string name = myProduct.Name;
```

I'm not sure if this method applied in the DataService Context or not.

**Edit**: I'm thinking Entity Framework/ApplicationDBContext. I think simon at rcl has the answer with linq.